# Can't setState inside useEffect with "useIsFocused()" from react-navigation as dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, use-state

I use the `useIsFocused()` function from `react-navigation/native` as a dependency of `useEffect` to listen to screen focus, so when I navigate back it enters the `if` with the `isFocused` and the `myRoute.params.isChecked` to execute the function.

But it's not updating the route state on `setRoute(newRoute);` and `setIsLoading(false)`. The `setIsLoading(true)` inside the function is called but the one inside the useEffect route isn't because it never call the route update. The screen keeps loading infinitely because of that.

Why it not updates the `isLoading` and `route` states?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect, useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

const MyRoute = ({ navigation, route: myRoute }) => {
  const [route, setRoute] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  /** ... */ 

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('route call')
    if (Object.keys(route).length) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [route]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isLoading);
  }, [isLoading]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // trigger route refresh on navigate when checkin/checkout
    if (isFocused && myRoute.params?.isChecked) {
      const updateRouteWithCheckInOut = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const newRoute = route;

        for (let i = 0; i < newRoute.visitas.length; i++) {
          const { sub_id, check_in_out } = myRoute.params;

          if (newRoute.visitas[i].sub_id === sub_id) {
            newRoute.visitas[i].realizada = true;
            newRoute.visitas[i].check_in_out = check_in_out;
          }
        }
        debugger;

        setRoute(newRoute);
      };

      updateRouteWithCheckInOut();
    }
  }, [isFocused]);

  /** ... */
}
```

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: it always print `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are updating some properties of visitas array in your for loop.
the thing is you are just mutating some propery and update your route with the same object. if you check route === newRoute after the for loop you see that it evaluates to true. because they are the same object. and when you update your route with the same object react doesn't rerender your component.
you should update your route like this:

```
setRoute(...newRoute)
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem! Changed to `setRoute({ ...newRoute })`